# Packet generation for routing 

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, internals

As part of a coursework i am changing the kernel's ip lookup code, i have made the changes and i would like to test it .. 
how should i go about generating data for these ip lookups .. will changing /proc/sys/net/ip_forward to 1 help me generate the data i want ??

In other words, i have different sets of implementation for ip lookup in kernel and i would like to collect the statistics for these implementations , how should i go about it ..

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific? If you want to generate network data/flow easily you can use iperf, if you want to monitor network traffic as its entering/leaving a machine with your modified kernel then use wireshark.

If you are more specific, then I can help more.